# How do I configure vscode live server to process php files properly (I'm using Win10 and Chrome)?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am trying to develop web pages with `php` calls using `vscode` and `vscode live server`.  I have installed live server and it works fine with html/css/js.    However if the code I'm developing refers to a .php file, I just get the text of the php file, it is not executed by the server.  I did find `live-server-web-extensions` which installs into the chrome browser, presumably to do a reload when the php files are modified as well.

So what I need to know is: How do I configure the server to process php files?  I do have php.exe on my system, and if I used the php browser, things work fine.  But I'd like to use vscode and live server for development, and I'm missing the secret sauce.  I'm am using the Chrome browser and Windows 10.

Comment: You can't. Try using a different extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver

Comment: Does that also do the auto-refresh on save like live-server does?

Answer (score 10):

There exist an extension to create [php server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=brapifra.phpserver) directly in `VSCODE` for `php file`

1) Once you installed the extension right click on your `php` file and select the first option `PHP Server: serve project` and it will open localhost link in your browser.

2) Then you need two more things. One is [live-server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension and second is [live-server-web-extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-server-web-extension/fiegdmejfepffgpnejdinekhfieaogmj/) that needs to be installed in your browser.

3) open your php project with live server.

Press `F1` and type `open with live server`. It will open your php project having a port something similar to this `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` copy that link.

[image]

4) Then go to your `localhost` TAB and use your `live-server-web-extension` and paste the link that you have just copied and be sure to enable `live reload` and then Apply.

[image]

5) The last step is that you must copy your  `localhost` link and paste it in `Actual server Address` and then again apply.

[image]

Reload your `localhost` page and then you can see live change to your browser whenever you change something in your php code.

The complete [video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=107&v=54wcX1G2GH8&feature=emb_logo)

Comment: The live server address in live server web extension can also be localhost, no need for 127.0.0.1 - which is localhost in numeric expression.

Answer (score 7):

No need for an extension - the [PHP CLI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) actually comes with a [built-in webserver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Just run the following command:

```sh
php -S localhost:2222
```

If you really wanted to bake this into VSCode, you could add a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) to execute it for you.

Comment: This is the better answer, IMO. No installing extra servers and extensions you don't need, just run it straight from php