# is there a way to live update/reload my php pages when am on a localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sass

I Use VScode, xammp and firefox developer edition is there a way to live reload my website in the browser.The only thing i tried was to just change the extension from PHP to HTML and use live reload extension in vscode.

Comment: This works with Chrome, not sure if the same extension is available for firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255030/how-do-i-configure-vscode-live-server-to-process-php-files-properly-im-using-w

Comment: It worked thank you ADYSON